How can I use method setInitializationExceptionHandler() in Android WorkManager configuration
For configuring Android Work Manager there is this method
setInitializationExceptionHandler()

How can I use this? How it can be helpful for me?
My problem, that we have a lot of crashes (1.8K for the last 30 days for 8 users)

Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
The file system on the device is in a bad state. WorkManager cannot access the app's internal data store.

in production, but we can not reproduce it, so we can not fix it.
